How realistic is it that this house has one bedroom?
This fan-wiki page shows the house of Nick and Juliette.
Fandom Wiki

From the start of Season 2 Juliette has entirely forgotten Nick and their relationship is functionality reset. This is awkward as they are living together. The show resolves this dilemma by having Nick sleep on the couch.
This from a UK perspective seems ridiculous. The house internally and externally is huge, why does it not have a second bedroom?

@jwodder wow, I have upvoted the top answer on that question. #embarassed

There was more than one bedroom. When trouble stayed there she slept in a bedroom. I think it's a common trope that when a couple is having problems, the husband sleeps on the couch. Or it could be that Juliet felt that the second bedroom was too close to hers and she wanted the distance of a floor between them.
